# Le genre des villes

Tags: genre

Le genre des pays est bien expliqué dans les livres de grammaire.

Quelles sont les règles qui dictent le genres des villes ?

On dit, p.ex., la ville de Marseille est chargée d'histoire mais aussi Marseille est actif et la belle Marseille. Paris est masculin mais Rome féminin. Certaines villes françaises sont féminins (Lille, Strasbourg, Lyon, etc.).

Pourquoi ?

Comment: Good question, but asked several times akready. A search for "genre des villes" turns up several for your reference — including my own which was closed as a duplicate :p

Comment: J'ai fait le tour de cette question ici. http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=108.0

Comment: @aCOSwt Peux-tu poster ta réponse ici ?

Comment: @Luge Sawczak Duplicata mais c'est étonnant qu'il n'y pas de règles quand même ☺